# What does the call sign of the uptime mean (output of htop)?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, uptime

I've runnting a ubuntu 12.04 and a 14.04 instance. If I call the uptime, the instance of version 12.04 returns: `65 days` and the one of 14.04 returns: `112 days(!)`. I want to know the meaning of the `(!)` sign. Is it just specific to ubuntu 14.04 or does it have a special meaning?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just an indicator which appears when your system has been up for more than 100 days.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is the output of the uptime command, but it might be htop, which does indeed put an exclamation mark in if you have more than 100 days of uptime.
https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/master/UptimeMeter.c#L36